# prototyping functions in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I have two functions, `f` and `g`, which call each other recursively. Unfortunately, when `f` calls `g`, it has not yet been declared, so I get an "unbound variable" error.  How can I prototype (or whatever the equivalent vocabulary is) this function in SML/NJ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `and`:

```
fun f x = ... 
and g x = ...
```

More info [here](http://www.dcs.napier.ac.uk/~cs66/course-notes/sml/lesson8.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Mutual Recursion. Use **`and`** instead of **`fun`** between the two functions.